# VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, manjaro, aur

I'm new to Manjaro and AUR, having an almost same problem like [this one on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705720/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed-error-despite-running-sbin-vboxconfig):

I have `vagrant`, `virtualbox` installed via `pacman`, then I try

`$ vagrant up`

> VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
> run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
> message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.

`$ VBoxManage --version`

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no
> module
> available for the current kernel (4.9.20-1-MANJARO) or it failed to
> load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>        sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
>
>      You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```
>
> 5.1.20r114628

`$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

> sudo: /sbin/vboxconfig: command not found

According to the link I post, I try `$ sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

> sudo: /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh: command not found

I also find suggestion to `modprobe vboxdrv`:

`$ modprobe vboxdrv`

> modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.20-1-MANJARO

`$ dkms`

> Usage: /usr/bin/dkms [action] [options]   [action]  = { add | remove |
> build | install | uninstall | match | autoinstall
> | mkdriverdisk | mktarball | ldtarball | mkrpm | mkkmp | mkdeb | status }   [options] = [-m module] [-v module-version] [-k
> kernel-version] [-a arch]
> [-d distro] [-c dkms.conf-location] [-q] [--force] [--all]
> [--templatekernel=kernel] [--directive='cli-directive=cli-value']
> [--config=kernel-.config-location] [--archive=tarball-location]
> [--kernelsourcedir=source-location] [--no-prepare-kernel] [--no-initrd]
> [--binaries-only] [--source-only] [-r release (SuSE)] [--verbose]
> [--size] [--spec=specfile] [--media=floppy|iso|tar] [--legacy-postinst=0|1]
> [--no-depmod]
> [-j number] Error! No action was specified.

`dkms` seems alright?

`$ dkms status`
prints nothing.

`gcc` has been installed .

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to **install**

```
sudo pacman -S [kernel version]-virtualbox-host-modules
```

get kernel version: `uname -r`

Your user must be in the following **groups**

- `vboxusers` for virtualbox to work
- `storage` group (for the usb subsystem)
- `vboxsf` group (to share files).
- `uucp`group for serial port

To add a user to group vboxuser:
`gpasswd -a USERNAME vboxusers`

Check the: [manjaro wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox#Install_VirtualBox)
and  [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox)

Comment: `$ sudo pacman -S virtualbox-host-modules-arch` give me
`error: target not found: virtualbox-host-modules-arch`

Comment: `sudo pacman -S linux37-virtualbox-host-modules` with linux kernel 3.7. https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox#Install_VirtualBox

Comment: Yep, I've installed `linux49-virtualbox-host-modules`

Comment: added user to vboxusers group?

Comment: It works ... for no reason after I reboot

Comment: No idea why, but after adding to `vboxusers` and reboot, everything just worked.

Comment: @Wentao Glad you commented about the restart, it worked for me too.

Comment: adding user to vboxusers is done as a part of insallation. follow the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248315/sign-virtual-box-modules-vboxdrv-vboxnetflt-vboxnetadp-vboxpci-centos-8`

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting my machine did the trick. This loaded the kernel modules for VirtualBox. I'm sure there is also a way to do this manually, but I didn't bother trying to figure it out when rebooting took less time.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while starting a Windows7 VM on Arch for the first time after installing VirtualBox.

In my case running `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` gave no output (though there was no FATAL error as OP faced). Also `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` command was not found.

Running `rcvboxdrv` seemed to do the trick:

```
$ sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv
Unloading modules: vboxdrv 
Loading modules: vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv
```

No reboot was required! The VM worked fine after that.

Comment: I had the error the very first time of doing a vagrant up on Manjaro, and this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

works each time I have this error from my VM machine, after which

```
vagrant up
```

runs as expected.

Comment: Actually this seems to be a corruption that arises when the vagrant is not halted or machine has been switched off without halting vagrant. Each time sudo modprobe vboxdrv on vagrant location fixes this.