# Can't install CentOS VirtualBox guest additions

Tags: centos, virtualbox, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro Linux, and I have CentOS 7 installed in VirtualBox. When I try to install VirtualBox Guest Additions, I get the following error.

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.28 Guest Additions for Linux...........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.1.28 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details.
Press Return to close this window...
```

The content of `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` follows.

```
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed.
```

The content of `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log` follows.

```
grep: /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j2 modules
arch/x86/Makefile:96: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
Makefile:641: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
cat: write error: Broken pipe
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem  -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/
  include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-
  strict-aliasing -fno-conmon -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -02 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-red-
  zone -mcmodel=kernel -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fno-omit-
  frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling-h -fno-pie -I/Lib/modules/
  3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/
  vbox.0/vboxguest/rOdrv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RINGO -DIN_RT_RO -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_RO -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -
  DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64 BITS GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest_linux)"  -
  D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem  -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/
  generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-
  aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -std=gnu89 -02 -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-red-zone -
  mcmodel=kernel -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fno-omit-frame-
  pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -fno-pie -I/lib/modules/
  3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/
  vbox.0/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RINGO -DIN_RT_RO -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_RO -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -
  DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME-KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest)"  -
  D"KBUTLD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxGuest.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest.c
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxguest] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Thank's guys, my problem was solved by running  `sudo yum update` then

```
sudo yum install -y gcc kernel-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides installing the host module in manjaro, and adding the manjaro user which is running the vbox to the groups both explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361617/virtualbox-is-complaining-that-the-kernel-module-is-not-loaded/361633#361633)

It seems that you need to install the development tools in the VM's CentOS. According to your screenshot - you don't have `gcc` installed. To do that run

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Now you should be able to compile the guest addons in CentOS.

Comment: I have tried This solution but it doesn't work.